# Authentication Issue while installing Microsoft Visual c++ 2008 Redistributable package

Tags: go, installation, silent

When i try to install Microsoft Redistributable package silently through golang i get this error

**

> fork/exec C:\Windows2008R2.exe: The requested operation requires
>   elevation.

**

And my code is as follows

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    co := exec.Command("C:\\Windows2008R2.exe","/q","/c:\"msiexec","/i","Windows2008R2.msi","/qn","/l*v","C:\\Windows2008R2_x64.log\"")
    if err := co.Run(); err != nil { 
        fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
    }  
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to run it as Administrator?

Comment: Yes I tried to Run this as Administrator still have the same problem

Comment: I don't know Go, but it looks like you have to find a way to make the `exec.Command()` function run the program with admin rights. Sorry for not being more helpful :)

Comment: One more thing... Do you know the `runas` command? For example like this: `runas /user:Administrator "C:\Windows2008R2.exe"`. It will prompt for the admin password, so I do not know if it is possible to use it in your situation, but you could try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are not the owner of the file.
In order to change the ownership of the files you can...

1. go in to the properties of the folder that contains the files you need to take ownership of
2. click on the security tab
3. click Advanced
4. click on the Owner tab
5. Click Edit...
6. Select the account name in the Change owner to list that you want to take ownership
7. Check the box, Replace owner on subcontainers and objects
8. Click OK